# AngularJS and jqueryUI apply new index of list elements

Tags: jquery-ui, angularjs

I'm currently finishing a feature with list reordering and I'm stuck with a probably very simple thing, but I'm really sorry that I can't figure out how to solve it .... ( possibly my brain just ignores this logic :) )

### The purpose is simple :

I have a list of items with a "position" data (different from $index).
I drag and drop items to change their order.
When the drag stops, all items in the list should have a new position, that'll be updated with a $resource object.

For example, after dragging I have this:

```
 $index   elem.position
   0           2
   1           1
   2           3
```

should automatically change position 2->1, 1->2 and 3->3.

### The problem :

With angularUI I can have the **current** item index but not the others in the list. So I can't change the whole list index after stopping the drag. And it's frustrating because on view, I can catch easily $index but not in controller.

### Code :

in controller.js

```
 $scope.updateSortable = {
  stop: function(e, ui) {
    for (var i=0; i<$scope.list.length; i++) {
      var elem = $scope.list[i];
      // here's don't know how to update elem.position 
      //elem.position = ui.item.index; // bad one, I know :)
      //elem.$update();
    }
  },
    placeholder: "xp-hightlight",
    axis: 'y'
};
```

in html page :

```
 <div ng-repeat="el in list">
    <div>
      <span class="position" ng-bind="el.position"></span>
    </div>
 </div>
```

The json items look like that :

```
 { id: 47, description: "my text in the list", position: 1}
```

Comment: Is there any point where element.position != $index + 1 ?

Comment: nope, both should be logically the same/ I wanted to manage as it (position =$index+1) but can't get the $index in my controller. And my first trick was to do `ng-bind="$index+1`but that was just user-view

Answer (score 0):

Would this work for you, or do you have to have the position variable set?

```
<div ng-repeat="el in list">
    <div>
      <span class="position">{{$index + 1}}</span>
    </div>
 </div>
```

I added this to your controller 'testCtrl'. You can update the position element within the callback of this watch:

```
var _list;
$scope.$watch(function() {
  return JSON.stringify($scope.items)
},function(_l) {
  if(typeof _l !== 'undefined') {
    _list = JSON.parse(_l);
    console.log(_list)
  }
```

});

Comment: That's on user-view. I need to save the new position in database, thats why I need to go through it with controller

Comment: i === $index in this stop command. so why not just:

$scope.updateSortable = {
  stop: function(e, ui) {
    for (var i=0; i<$scope.list.length; i++) {
   $scope.list[i].position = i + 1;
    }
  },
  placeholder: "xp-hightlight",
  axis: 'y'
};

Comment: if we do i+1 it will be false in the case of moving position 3 to position 1 (so $index 2 -> 0)

Comment: I don't quite understand.. could you post a fiddle or plunker?

Comment: sure : http://plnkr.co/edit/kDkNLSjoHbnaumk2uaOF?p=preview  If you test it, when moving upper the items, you'll have an issue in the ordering

Comment: I found my issue. In the app, I have also a creation state that was also identified in the DOM for the sortable UI. So I put it out and the sorting was working well ! Thank you a lot for the help and also to give me a real nice and simple solution that works :)

Answer (score 0):

I just solved the issue, and thanks to koolunix I managed the update of position directly inside the controller with this plunkr :

http://plnkr.co/edit/kDkNLSjoHbnaumk2uaOF?p=preview

The main fact was just to manage the position with the loop in list items.

```
  elem.position=i+1;
```